# How can I replace multiple characters with just one (C++)?

Tags: c++

We have a char. We need to replace all `ab` characters from our char with the letter `c`.

Example we have :

```
abracadabra
```

the output will be :

```
cracadcra
```

I tried to use `replace()` function from C++, but no success.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
  {
  string test;
  cin>>test;
  
  for(int i=0;i<(strlen(test)-1);i++)
  {
      if((test[i]=='a')&&(test[i+1]=='b')){
  test.replace( test[i], 'c' );
      test.replace( test[i+1] , ' ' );     
      }
  }
  cout << test << endl;
  return 0;
  }enter code here
```

Comment: what have you tried? where did you get stuck? please show a [mre]

Comment: Why do not use `test.size()` instead of `strlen()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

That is not the syntax of `std::string::replace`.

**Solution:**

As is mentioned [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) the syntax is `std::string::replace(size_t pos,  size_t len,  const string& str)`. Do `test.replace(i, 2, "c" )` instead of `test.replace(test[i],'c')`.

Or use regular expressions as dtell pointed.

**Adittional information:**

1. `using namespace std;` is considered a bad practice (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).
2. You should use `std::string::size` instead of `strlen` when you're working with `std::string`.
3. To work with `std::string` you should use `#include <string>` instead of `#include <cstring>`.

**Full code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string test;
    std::cin >> test;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < test.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if((test[i]=='a') && (test[i+1]=='b'))
        {
            test.replace(i, 2, "c" );
        }
    }
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Regarding your point #3: the standard doesn't guarantee that `<string>` is already included in `<iostream>`, so the correct and portable way is to explicitly `#include <string>` when using `std::string`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++11 regex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string str = "abracadabra";
  std::regex r("ab");
  std::cout << std::regex_replace(str, r, "c") << "\n"; // cracadcra
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about regex function.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do by using the standard library is first to find `ab` and then replace it. The example code I wrote is finding string `ab` unless there is None in the string and replacing it with `c`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "abracadabra";
    int pos = -1;
    while ((pos = s.find("ab")) != -1)//finding the position of ab
        s.replace(pos, sizeof("ab") - 1, "c");//replace ab with c
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

//OUTPUT
cracadcra
```

Comment: Well, a regex solution is arguably easier.

Comment: But he doesn't know regular expressions, you can see that from his coding :)